# Equilibrium Uniqueness in a General Equilibrium Framework

Tags: microeconomics, general-equilibrium, competitive-equilibrium

I was wondering if anyone had any insight into the conditions that lead to a unique equilibrium in an exchange economy under a general equilibrium framework. More specifically, I know that the two "general" conditions that can be used to show an equilibrium is unique are **Gross Substitutes** and **Weak Axiom of Revealed Preference.**

But beyond that, I'm having trouble figuring out what those two conditions actually look like in practice, and finding examples for each case. For example, a few of the specific questions I have (and note, parts of my questions may themselves be wrong, so please do not hesitate to point out any and all flaws you see!):

In an Edgeworth Economy setting, both consumers having Cobb Douglas utility functions is sufficient, correct? I'm not 100% sure, but I think that satisfies the gross substitutes condition. That said, is that result generalize-able? If all individuals have Cobb Douglas utilities in an *n-consumer, l-good* case, is there still a unique equilibrium?

Similarly, in an Edgeworth Economy setting, if both individuals have quasilinear utilities *in the same good* it is also sufficient to show a unique equilibrium (if it exists). Is that result generalizable to an *n case*?

Moreover, if anyone else has any good examples of either utility function forms or tips regarding proving or disproving uniqueness in a given case, I'd love to hear them! I'm particularly curious about Edgeworth Economy cases, but any general examples/results would be wonderful!

Thanks so much!